# How to make a text box change depending on a dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, input, textbox, html.dropdownlistfor

I would like to know how to make a text box change according to a drop down menu. So for example ...

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<p>Product:</p>
<select id = "myPRODUCTS">
<option value = "Apple">Apple</option>
<option value = "Orange">Orange</option>
<option value = "Mango">Mango</option>
</select>
<p>Price:</p><input type="text" name="Price" readonly="readonly" />
```

So I want the price text box to change if I have selected Apple I want it to be £0.45 or if I select orange I want it to be £0.50 and so on. How would I do this?

Thanks in advance,
Marek

Comment: [Please show an attempted solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think you need js. For example you can put for each option a 'data-price' attribute, where store each price and then with js at change events get that attribute and pass it to the element you want.

Comment: Sounds a bit confusing

Comment: @Marek - It's a pretty standard approach, actually. It's only confusing until you learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shows how you can accomplish what you seek.
As others have mentioned, it's not exactly the most secure / efficient way to do this, especially if you're dealing with real money, but all you have to do to get this to work is add jquery to your html file with `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`

```
$('#myPRODUVTS').on('change', function() {
 fruit = $(this).val();
    if (fruit == 'Apple') {
        $('#Price').val('£0.45');
    }
    if (fruit == 'Orange') {
        $('#Price').val('£0.50');
    }
    if (fruit == 'Mango') {
        $('#Price').val('£0.65');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LtBh6/ this shows the code in action with your example.

Comment: Put the code I wrote for you in `<script></script>` tags, after your `</body>` tag at the bottom.  You can put the reference to the jquery.js file either in the same place or in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: I'm using chrome and don't have that issue.

Comment: It should work.  I don't think it'd make a difference but I'd recommend putting the reference to jquery in a `<head>` tag, above the `<body>` tag.  Your `<title>` tag also goes in the `<head>`.

Comment: Still doesn't work, but it doesn't matter. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 1):

You have do create a JS function that run onchange of the select.
That function will reload the page and atribute the value of the price to a variable, that you will use to give value to the price field.

Of course that you shuld have all those names and prices in a DB to be easier to select values.

:)

Some update:

DB with data
query fot that DB table called

> $result_consulta_mes ( in my example )

in samefile.php some Js that will get the value of the select and reload the same file with the variable.

```
<script>function unid()
{
    var mse=document.getElementById("select_mes");
    var mse2=mse.options[mse.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("mes_index").value = mse2;
    window.location.href = "samefile.php?rowmes=" + mse2;
}</script>
```

Then GET the variable value that came from the JS

```
<?php $varmes = "$_GET[rowmes]"; ?>
```

And the select with a while:

```
<input class="hidden" name="mes_index" type="text" id="mes_index" value= "<?php echo $varmes?>"><select data-size="20" id="select_mes" onchange="unid()" >
<?php
    $current_mes = $varmes;
    while($row_me = mysql_fetch_array($result_consulta_mes)){ 
    if ($row_me['mes_id'] == $current_mes){
    echo "<option selected value=" . $row_me['mes_id'] . ">" . $row_me['mes_mes'] . "</option>" ;}
    else {
    echo "<option value=" . $row_me['mes_id'] . ">" . $row_me['mes_mes'] . "</option>" ;}
    }
?></select>
```

Comment: It's my opinion that this should be a comment.

Comment: I agree with you but I can´t place comments, but I still try to help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @EricBrown let me desagree with you, if the DB tables where created, this script works just fine, providing acess to DB tables, much more data values and better managed. Also updated some input field for the instance of use it in a from. This code is part of some code of mine that is working very nice.