# display dropdown list in form using mysql data & insert record

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to have a dropdown list that shows data from a mysql database on a form to add records. I can't find the way to make it work and it doesn't display anything, so I can't even try it. I'm learing php and mysql so i don't know what can be wrong in the code, though the connection is fine. Suggestions? thanks in advance, here's the code.

```
<?php
 include("includes/connect.php");
 doDB();


if (!$_POST) {
$display_block = "
<form method=\"post\" action=\"".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."\">        

   <div class=\"form-group\">  
        <div class=\"row\">      
            <div class=\"col-md-8\">
      <label>Dominio</label>
     <input  class=\"form-control input-sm\" name=\"dominio\" type=\"text\"  placeholder=\"dominio\">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";


//get plan list
$get_planlist_sql = "SELECT * FROM PLANES ORDER BY plan ASC";
$get_planlist_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_planlist_sql)
    or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

if (mysqli_num_rows($get_planlist_res) > 0) {

    $display_block .="<div class=\"form-group\">  
<div class=\"row\">      
    <div class=\"col-md-8\">
        <label>Plan</label>
           <select class=\"form-control input-sm\">
            <option value=\"\>Selecciona</option>";

       while ($getplans = mysqli_fetch_array($get_planlist_res)) {
        $plan = $getplans{'plan'];
        $display_block .= "<option value=\"".$plan"\">".$plan."</option>";                   
    }

        $display_block .= "
        </select>
        <div class=\"form-actions\">
            <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-lg\">Ingresar usuario</button>
        </div>
        </form>";
}
//free result
    mysqli_free_result($get_planlist_res);


} else if ($_POST) {
//Revisar los campos requeridos
if (($_POST["dominio"] == "") || ($_POST["plan"] == "")) {
    header("Location: cliente.php");
    exit;
}

//Add to table datos_cliente
$add_datosclientes_sql = "INSERT INTO datos_cliente (dominio, plan) VALUES ('".$_POST["dominio"]."', '".$_POST["plan"]."')";
$add_datosclientes_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_datosclientes_sql)
or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
mysqli_close($mysqli);
     $display_block = "<p>La incidencia ha sido enviada. Deseas <a href=\"nuevo-cliente.php\">agregar otra</a>?</p>";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />


<title>Untitled Document</title>



</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<?php echo $display_block; ?>
</div>

</div><!--end container-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check my ansewer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922690/how-to-make-a-text-box-change-depending-on-a-dropdown-menu/23922797#23922797

Comment: syntax error -> `$plan = $getplans{'plan'];` should be `$plan = $getplans['plan'];`. You are also missing a quote in `<option value=\"\>Selecciona</option>";` -> should be `<option value=\"\">Selecciona</option>";`

Comment: You are also missing a `.` after the first `$plan` in `$display_block .= "<option value=\"".$plan"\">".$plan."</option>"; ` should be `$display_block .= "<option value=\"".$plan."\">".$plan."</option>";`. It would be helpful to you to turn error reporting on to debug, while still in development, or to use an IDE that does syntax error highlighting to catch these syntax issues.

Comment: Also there are several closing tags missing, specifically `</div>`.  I'd recommend indenting your code properly so you can more easily keep track of opening/closing tags.  It may not be causing this particular issue but it will help us in helping you.

Comment: thank you, recently switched to brackets and showed no errors. Fixed the issue of not displaying anything. The dropdown displays correctly with the info of the database, but none of the inputs are being stored